# Spring3 application tomcat7 to Tomcat8 upgrade error - context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

Tags: java, tomcat8, spring-3

I am trying to upgrade my java spring3 web application from Tomcat7 to Tomcat 8. When I try to start the application I am getting the below error in catalina.out

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Tomcat:apache-tomcat-8.0.42

Java: "1.8.0_252"

```
26-Mar-2021 16:38:47.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
26-Mar-2021 16:38:47.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.42
26-Mar-2021 16:38:47.134 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.42/webapps/evidya.war
26-Mar-2021 16:38:55.154 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this l                                             ogger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2021-03-26 16:38:55,225 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the sa                                             me package
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2567)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2567)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2567)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2567)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.determineContextClass(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:333)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:281)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
26-Mar-2021 16:38:55.228 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropri                                             ate container log file
26-Mar-2021 16:38:55.232 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/evidya] startup failed due to previous errors
26-Mar-2021 16:38:55.249 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.42/webapps/evidya.war has fi                                             nished in 8,115 ms
```

Comment: Can I debug and than say what class is missed ?

Comment: Do you intentionally run Tomcat with a `SecurityManager` (`-security` command line parameter)? Little remark: since you are doing the effort to upgrade Tomcat, don't use a version which already reached end-of-life. Try Tomcat 9.0 instead.